# Record condenser mic and acoustic guitar in the same time?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, recording, homerecording, microphones

I am wondering if with Audio interfaces such as the Scarlett 4i4 is it possible to plug a mic with +48V phantom power in line 1 and plug a guitar into line 2?
I mean, if I activate the +48V power, I guess it will be activated for both of the two frontal channels, and I guess the guitar will not work in a 48V line, or it is something automatic that the Audio interface can manage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  According to focusrite, ["48V Phantom power is not sent to any 1/4" jack inputs, these are used for line or instrument inputs."](https://support.focusrite.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115005178505-What-is-Phantom-Power-48V-)  So, plug the microphone into your interface with an XLR cable, and plug the guitar into your interface with a 1/4" instrument cable.  It will work.

Answer (score 5):

The phantom power is only applied across pins on the XLR connections. A guitar plugged in with a 1/4” cable will not have the phantom power voltage on that connection.

Comment: To emphasise - phantom is ***never*** on jacks, only on XLRs. Almost any equipment built in the past 50 years to use XLR is 'aware' of this & will not be damaged if phantom is on but the mic doesn't need it. The plugs/sockets are also designed in such a way that plugging whilst phantom is on is actually **better** for the equipment than switching it on or off once connected [don't do that if you can help it].